# Why does aria require role="tab" underneath role="tablist"?

Tags: wai-aria

I've always given `<ul>` elements container class names such as `<ul class="cars">` where it was then assumed every inner `<li>` element is a car.

If the [aria spec defines tablist](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#tablist) with Required Owned Elements as 'tab', and [defines tab](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#tab) as requiring a context role of 'tablist', then what's the point of having tab at all?  Can't it be assumed?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not an object oriented language and doesn't have type checking so even if you have child objects of a parent, you still have to specify the types of the child objects.  In your `<ul>` example, you still had to use `<li>` elements as children.  Using your reasoning, you're saying that you shouldn't have to use `<li>` on the children.  That it should be assumed the child nodes will be `<li>`.

Same with specifying roles.  Use the proper parent and child roles.

Comment: Can you explain a purpose to it though?  It still feels very redundant to me i.e. no meaningful benefit gained.

Comment: A `tablist` is a container that will have `tab` elements, similar to how a `<ul>` is a container for `<li>` elements or a `<table>` is a container for `<tr>` elements.  Further, each `tab` will have an associated `tabpanel`.  The tab/tabpanel relationship is not parent/child but rather an `aria-controls` relationship.  You can see more at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel.

Comment: You're explaining how it is but not what functionality it provides.  'If role="tab" were assumed instead of declared, then <screen readers wouldn't be able to do this>'

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand what you're asking for.  The functionality of hearing "tab" is the same as hearing "button" or "link" or "table".  It gives the screen reader user a clue as to the purpose of the object and how to interact with it.  When I hear "tab", that gives me certain expectations.  It also gives the object a proper role so that I can use screen reader quick navigation keys to quickly navigate to the object (the apostrophe key in JAWS takes me to the next tab element).  Without the role, the quick key would not work.

Comment: I'm looking at it from the perspective of a screen reader software dev.  Let's assume the spec doesn't say anything about a tab, that there only exists 'tablist' where all its children are assumed tabs.  As a screen reader dev I follow the spec and use `const tabs = document.querySelector('[role="tablist"]').children` then go on my merry way of a functionally equivalent experience.  I don't see how declaring role="tab" allows me any more functionality than without.

Comment: Same with `<ul>`.  You can't just get all the children of a `<ul>` and assume they're `<li>` elements.  There's no type checking and any element could be put in a `<ul>`, albeit not valid html (except `<script>` is allowed).

Comment: In the scenario I described, the spec explicitly says 'all children of role="tablist" are tabs'.  So yes, per the hypothetical spec, I can definitely assume they are tabs.

Comment: I explained why it was needed.  You are certainly free to ignore it.

Comment: No you didn't because the only deciding factor on whether an element is "valid" is whether the spec says so.  If the spec says all children of role="tablist" are valid tabs, then they are valid tabs - no questions.  Your constant comparisons to <ul> are irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't see the relevance.